# Every 2nd invocation of API call enableDataSharingWithApplicationGroupIdentifier in iOS Share extension crashes with the error

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, ios-extensions

Every 2nd invocation of a iOS Share Extension crashes.

Uncaught exception: 'enableDataSharingWithApplicationGroupIdentifier:containingApplication:' must be called before 'setApplicationId:clientKey'

I'm using Parse iOS SDK 1.7.4

My code is as follows

```
[Parse enableDataSharingWithApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"group.abc.xyz"
                                 containingApplication:@"com.abc.xyz"];    
[Parse setApplicationId:@"xxxxx" clientKey:@"yyyyy"];
```

Any thoughts what could be wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(![Parse applicationGroupIdentifierForDataSharing]) {
    [Parse enableDataSharingWithApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"group.abc.xyz"
                                     containingApplication:@"com.abc.xyz"];
    [Parse setApplicationId:@"xxxxx" clientKey:@"yyyyy"];
}
```